# Get Windows Service and ASP website on Windows 2008 to read same Registry Keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services, registry, wow64

I have a shared class which calls the following registry key which is used by a Windows Service and also an ASP MVC3 website:

```
irsalKey = Registry.LocalMachine
                    .CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE")
                    .CreateSubKey("MyApp");
```

On my local (Win7 32bit) PC this works as expected.

On my test 2008 server, the Service read/writes the "Wow6432" node, but website does not?
My guess is that the service is 32bit (uses 32 bit binaries) but the website is 64bit under IIS?

What can I do so that both read/write the same keys?
It doesn't matter WHICH key this is, but it needs to be the same for both!

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling pointed me to use the following:

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
```

It IS in MSDN, but the documentation wasn't too clear (to me anyway!) but this forces any RegistryKey to use it's 32bit version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly compiling the website for x86 instead of AnyCPU - that might force it to 32 bit mode. (set up a new platform in the Build/Configuration Manager menu)

You'd also have to turn on the app pool option in IIS to enable 32 bit applications (advanced settings on the app pool).